# Como posso executar uma função que está noutro form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho dois forms, num deles tenho:

```
namespace J13_Rouparia_CS
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
          public static int LocPesq; 
          public static string peqNume;
          public static string peqArti;

          public void UpdatePesquisa()
          {
              switch (LocPesq)
              {
                 case 1:
                     txtSRnum.Text = peqNume;
                     txtSRartigo.Text = peqArti;
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     txtELnum.Text = peqNume;
                     txtELartigo.Text = peqArti;
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     txtSLnum.Text = peqNume;
                     txtSLartigo.Text = peqArti;
                     break;
              }  
         }
    }
}
```

No outro eu gostaria de executar o `UpdatePesquisa()`, usando `frmMain.UpdatePesquisa()`, mas o método `UpdatePesquisa` não aparece na lista. Como posso resolver esta situação?

Answer (score 1):

Precisa ter a variável do seu `form` instanciada no local que você está chamando o método `UpdateProgress()`.

O seu `form` já está ativo? Caso contrário, você terá que instanciar a variável e chamar o método:

```
frmMain fMain = new frmMain();
fMain.UpdatePesquisa();
```

Se o seu formulário já está ativo, você tem duas opções:

- Enviar o formulário principal como parêmetro no construtor da classe que você utilizará:

  ```
  public partial class frmMain : Form {
     public frmMain(FormReferencia x) {…}
  }
  ```
- Utilizar a função `Application.OpenForms["<nome da classe>"]`:

  ```
  Form1 f1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
  ```

Comment: Eu risquei a primeira frase da sua resposta porque está incorreta, na verdade o método só pode ser visualizado fora da classe se for público, mas não quis mudar sua resposta e deixei para você editar, OK? Eu também esqueci de alterar o nome do método de `UpdateProgress()` para `UpdatePesquisa()`, fiz uma segunda edição mas não sei se será aceita, então qualquer coisa depois você altera, por favor. Agora, sobre essa primeira sugestão que você deu com o form ativo, creio que seja difícil que o segundo form esteja aberto **antes** do `frmMain`, que, pelo nome, é o principal!

Comment: Pedro, Obrigado pela ajuda! Realmente ficou confusa a resposta. Sobre o nome do formulario, eu também acho que já está ativo, mas achei melhor informar a solução caso não esteja.

Comment: Esse trecho da sua resposta: "*Você não conseguirá visualizar o método porque ele é public*" está errado. O método ser público não é o motivo dele não poder ser visualizado, pelo contrário, se não fosse público, aí sim que não seria visualizado. Por isso eu tinha riscado essa parte, eu esperava que você excluísse ela! E tem outro `UpdateProgress()` errado no primeiro parágrafo.

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do princípio que quer aceder ao form `frmMain` a partir de um outro evocado por esse mesmo `Form`, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

### frmMain

```
/// <summary>
/// Método localizado em "frmMain"
/// Criar uma nova instância do novo form
/// passando este como "Owner"
/// </summary>
void AbrirNovoForm()
{
    frmNovoForm frmNovoForm = new frmNovoForm();
    frmNovoForm.Show(this);
}
```

### frmNovoForm

```
/// <summary>
/// Método localizado em "frmNovoForm"
/// Fazer cast do "Owner" para "frmMain" e evocar o método "UpdatePesquisa()"
/// </summary>
void UpdatePesquisa() => (Owner as frmMain).UpdatePesquisa();
```

Answer (score 0):

a melhor forma de se fazer, vai depender muito do propósito, mas se entendi bem, uma forma de compartilhar o código entre formulários que possuem os mesmos campos, seria criar um form Base, colocar nele tudo que é comum para os demais, e os novos forms passam a herdar desse form Base, exemplo:

form Base:

```
public class frmBase : Form
{
  public void UpdatePesquisa()
  {
    //faz alguma coisa
  }
}
```

Novo Form:

```
public class frmNovo : frmBase
{
  //executa o que está no base
  base.UpdatePesquisa();
}
```

obs: se você também pode usar a palavra virtual no método criado no form base com isso você além de conseguir utilizar poderá sobrescrever nos novos forms.

exemplo com virtural:

```
public virtual void UpdatePesquisa()
{
   //faz alguma coisa form base
}
//form Novo poderia sobrescrever metodo acima
public override void UpdatePesquisa()
{
  //faz algo diferente do base, ou mesmo faz o que tem no base mas alguma coisa
}
```